# why does nmap shows same ports sometimes as filtered and sometimes as closed?

Tags: networking, tcp, nmap

When I'm scanning port range 4050-4060 of an smart metering device all ports are reported as closed:

```
root@abc:~/rvm/dlms# nmap -p 4050-4060 192.168.1.242

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-08 15:09 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.242
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4050/tcp closed unknown
4051/tcp closed unknown
4052/tcp closed unknown
4053/tcp closed unknown
4054/tcp closed unknown
4055/tcp closed unknown
4056/tcp closed lms
4057/tcp closed unknown
4058/tcp closed kingfisher
4059/tcp closed unknown
4060/tcp closed unknown
MAC Address: 00:0F:93:00:C8:E5 (Landis+Gyr)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.40 seconds
```

When I'm scanning port range 4050-4059 (only seconds later) some ports are reported as closed, some as filtered:

```
root@abc:~/rvm/dlms# nmap -p 4050-4059 192.168.1.242

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-08 15:10 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.242
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
4050/tcp closed   unknown
4051/tcp filtered unknown
4052/tcp closed   unknown
4053/tcp closed   unknown
4054/tcp closed   unknown
4055/tcp filtered unknown
4056/tcp filtered lms
4057/tcp closed   unknown
4058/tcp closed   kingfisher
4059/tcp filtered unknown
MAC Address: 00:0F:93:00:C8:E5 (Landis+Gyr)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.44 seconds
```

Anybody any idea?

Comment: See my answer [on networkengineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23398/strange-nmap-scan-results/23400#23400)